# Cache manifest not working in safari using cross-domain refs and SSL

Tags: html, caching, https, safari, offline

I have been trying to get my HTML5 offline cache manifest to work nicely in Safari when accessing the site with HTTPS.

I have the following setup:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" manifest="app.appcache">
<head>
  <base href="https://www.example.com">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//some.cdn.com/styles.css" charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//some.cdn.com/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

app.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
//some.cdn.com/styles.css
//some.cdn.com/app.js

NETWORK:
*
```

**Accessing my site over HTTP** works fine! Assets get loaded correctly and cached; I can use my app offline

**Accessing my site over HTTPS in Chrome** works fine as well

**Accessing my site over HTTPS in Safari** breaks :-( Assets get loaded normally, but won't cache. Debugging didn't got me any further. No useful information in the logs

According to the specs, referring to another domain in the cache manifest is allowed.

I have also tried using http:// or https:// explicitly in my HTML and manifest instead of the //-notation. Of no avail.

In my search online I've found some comments about cross-domain requests and that it isn't allowed in the cache manifest, but according to the W3C specs this is allowed (and proved by the fact that the browsers I tested it cache all the assets correctly, except for the combination **https & safari**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently I missed an important restriction of the appcache.
As mentioned in https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html:

> If the manifest's  is https: or another scheme intended for encrypted data transfer, then all URLs in explicit sections must have the same origin as the manifest itself.